# What is the correct way to add property value in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm trying to use `application.properties` file values in `controller`. Using following code.

```
@Value("${app.baseURL}")
private final String BaseUrl;
```

I found another way to do this.

```
@Controller
public class userController {

   String BaseUrl;
    public userController(@Value("app.baseURL")String BaseUrl) {
        this.BaseUrl= BaseUrl;
    }
}
```

What is the efficient way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the efficient way ?

No one of them is more efficient.
The first one uses the field injection and the second one the constructor injection.

I see rather a real difference in terms of design.
The first one set `BaseUrl` as an internal dependency that clients of the class cannot set. Only Spring can.
In most of cases, it is a bad idea as it buries class dependencies.
A common issue with this kind of design is unit testing.
As you write an unit test you have to have simple and natural ways to set the dependencies of the instance under test.
How to do that with an not accessible field ?
Reflection ? Not fine either.
The constructor injection of your second code is a much better way.

Comment: Spring Boot however provides you a simple way to pass property values using @TestPropertySource

Comment: @Satyendra Kumar Very good remark. But this annotation can be used only as you load the  Spring container : that is for an integration/sociable test. As you write a plain unit test, you don't load the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have few fields then use **@Value** at field level not at method level. If there are maximum number of property you have to use then use autowire **Environment**.

```
@Value("${app.baseURL}")
private final String BaseUrl;
```

Autowire Environment

```
@Autowired 
Environment env;
```

To get the property value by key using Environment

```
env.getProperty("some-strProp")
```

Comment: thanks dude. I think we can use this in constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of properties belong to each other you also can use a property class

application.yml:

```
    your:
      properties:
        root: 
          path: "/root/path/to/resource"
          enabled: true
          timeout: 10
```

java class:

```
    @ConfigurationProperties("your.properties.root")
    public class MyProperties {
        private String path;
        private boolean enabled;
        private int timeout;
        //getter & setter
    }
```

use constructor injection to access the properties:

```
    @Service
    public class MyService {

      private final MyProperties properties;

      @Autowired
      public MyService(MyProperties properties) {
          this.properties = properties;
      }
    }
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

you also can validate property classes:

```
    @Validated
    @ConfigurationProperties("your.properties.root")
    public class MyProperties {

        @NotEmpty
        private String path;

        @NotNull
        private Boolean enabled;

        @Min(1)
        private int timeout;

        //getter & setter
    }
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation

Comment: Thanks! @hyphen. So how can we use **COMMON SPRING BOOT PROPERTIES** in application.yml.  `spring.port=8090`

Comment: hi, you can just write any spring property in yml format :) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties

Comment: get it bro. Looks like yml format clean & readable. Anyway thanks dude!